# Using function return in if/else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I wanna to make my code look nicer.
Example:

```
result = somefunction()
if result == what_i_need:
    do_something()
else:
    print 'that\'s not what i need', result
```

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
if somefunction() == what_i_need:
    do_something()
else:
    print 'that\'s not what i need', <return value of somefunction>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Storing `<return value of somefunction>` is the _whole point_ of saving a reference, and you were _already doing it_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something you could technically try, but shouldn't:

```
def somefunction():
    val = 3 # calculate value
    globals()['somefunction_return'] = val # store it in globals() first
    return val # return as normal

def do_something():
    print 'got it'

what_i_need = 3

if somefunction() == what_i_need:
    do_something()
    print 'that\'s not what i need', somefunction_return

# result:
#
# got it
# that's not what i need 3
```

Why shouldn't you do this?

1. The assignment is still happening somewhere else, so all its done is sweep the unwanted code out of the way. Pay no attention to the garbage behind the curtain.
2. Messing with `globals()` is more fragile than a simple assignment done in the way you're already doing it, partly because it's more difficult for the developer to avoid tripping over it.
3. It introduces something called "side effects," extra events that a function does without saying so. In this example, `somefunction` is doing something in addition to its planned purpose, without advertising as much. This makes code much harder to maintain.
4. It makes the code more difficult to read and follow, which goes against the intent of Python. Imagine that someone is reading the `if` structure above. How are they supposed to know where `somefunction_return` came from? They would have to look through every line of code until they found the offending side effect in `somefunction`. We might have even named it something else, like `my_foobar_value`, and then the reader wouldn't even have a hint that they should check `somefunction`.

Please continue to use the ordinary assignment you already have in place.

Comment: Thank you kind man. So i will use ordinary assignment. I just like _similar_ syntax in try/except statement `except socket.gaierror, e: return('Error during socket closing: %s' % e)` and i imagine what it would be nice to make something like this in if/else statement.

Comment: The `except` statement captures the error and assigns it to `e`; the syntax is slightly different but it's still an explicit assignment.

Answer (score 2):

No, the only sensible way to capture a function's return value in Python is to explicitly assign it to a variable.

Even if there was a device for referring to a previous function's return value through implicit means, Python culture abhors this sort of thing. One oft-cited Python principle is "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: Can we use `as` keyword here for assgin function return to a variable?

Comment: `def get_a(): return "a"` and then `print get_a()`. Isn't this what OP is looking for?

Comment: @Arman I don't think you can; and anyway, `as` is just another method of assignment.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't understand what you mean, or how the code you show would be useful.